# How to use different NuGet package versions in different projects?

Tags: web-config, nuget-package, assemblybinding

I would like to use two different versions of the same nuget package. BUT I would like to use these in separate projects within my solution. I had expected this not to be a problem, but it looks as though (while the NuGet tool is happy to install different versions in different projects) the runtime is not happy to reference them.

To explain, I have projects A and B in my solution. Project A would like to use Acme nuget package version 1.0.0 and project B would like to use Acme nuget package version 2.0.0.

The error I get is this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Acme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1a2b34567890123' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

Of course, project A is referencing the class library project B - I believe that this is, essentially, what is causing the problem.

How can I convince my solution to allow each project to use their desired nuget version?